# Data structure for holding sets of interchangeable strings

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

I have a set of strings. Out of these, groups of 2 or more may represent the same thing. These groups should be stored in a way that given any member of the group, you can fetch other members of the group with high efficiency.

So given this initial set: `["a","b1","b2","c1","c2","c3"]` the result structure should be something like `["a",["b1","b2"],["c1","c2","c3"]]` and Fetch("b") should return `["b1","b2"]`.

Is there a specific data structure and/or algorithm for this purpose?

EDIT: "b1" and "b2" are not actual strings, they're indicating that the 2 belong to the same group. Otherwise a Trie would be a perfect fit.

Comment: is it a specific programming language programming question?  if not this may belong to computer science stackexchange and not here. if you do refer to a specific programming question and language please edit accordinagly

Comment: Sounds like [disjoint-set forests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) but backwards...

Comment: Would you show your exact problem, currently is ambiguous what are your groups?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri groups are pre-defined. So for example it is known that strings "b1" and "b2" belong to the same group when building the structure.

Comment: What are the criteria that tells us that two strings belong to the same group? If it is as simple as seeing whether the string has a certain prefix/suffix/substring/structure, you can simply group them together in a single pass through the list. If it is more like a set of relationships between pairs of strings, you will need to model it  as a graph and run a bfs/dfs or use disjoint sets to group them.

Comment: @MAK - The definition of the groups seems to be irrelevant to the question.

Comment: @TedHopp: Seemed relevant to me to formulate a solution. But maybe I misunderstood what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misinterpreting the initial problem setup, but I believe that there is a simple and elegant solution to this problem using off-the-shelf data structures.  The idea is, at a high level, to create a map from strings to sets of strings.  Each key in the map will be associated with the set of strings that it's equal to.  Assuming that each string in a group is mapped to the same set of strings, this can be done time- and space-efficiently.

The algorithm would probably look like this:

1. Construct a map M from strings to sets of strings.
2. Group all strings together that are equal to one another (this step depends on how the strings and groups are specified).
3. For each cluster:

   1. Create a canonical set of the strings in that cluster.
   2. Add each string to the map as a key whose value is the canonical set.

This algorithm and the resulting data structure is quite efficient.  Assuming that you already know the clusters in advance, this process (using a trie as the implementation of the map and a simple list as the data structure for the sets) requires you to visit each character of each input string exactly twice - once when inserting it into the trie and once when adding it to the set of strings equal to it, assuming that you're making a deep copy.  This is therefore an O(n) algorithm.

Moreover, lookup is quite fast - to find the set of strings equal to some string, just walk the trie to find the string, look up the associated set of strings, then iterate over it.  This takes O(L + k) time, where L is the length of the string and k is the number of matches.

Hope this helps, and let me know if I've misinterpreted the problem statement!

Answer (score 1):

Since this is Java, I would use a `HashMap<String, Set<String>>`. This would map each string to its equivalence set (which would contain that string and all others that belong to the same group). How you would construct the equivalence sets from the input depends on how you define "equivalent". If the inputs are in order by group (but not actually grouped), and if you had a predicate implemented to test equivalence, you could do something like this:

```
boolean differentGroups(String a, String b) {
    // equivalence test (must handle a == null)
}

Map<String, Set<String>> makeMap(ArrayList<String> input) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
    String representative = null;
    Set<String> group;
    for (String next : input) {
        if (differentGroups(representative, next)) {
            representative = next;
            group = new HashSet<String>();
        }
        group.add(next);
        map.put(next, group);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Note that this only works if the groups are contiguous elements in the input. If they aren't you'll need more complex bookkeeping to build the group structure.